# Frame.ReadCsv not correctly parsing multiline column names

Tags: c#, deedle

Say we have a file named **input.csv** containing the following text:

```
"
col_A
";"
col_A
2";col_B
1;2;3
4;5;6
```

If I try to execute the following instruction (using C#)

```
var f = Frame.ReadCsv("input.csv", separators: ";");
```

I can observe, by placing a breakpoint right next to it, that f.ColumnKeys elements are equal to `[ "col_A", "col_A\r", "col_B" ]`, meaning that the method isn't correctly parsing the header.

In another scenario I even got a System.ArgumentException telling me that a duplicate key was found (the scenario was similar to the one I provided above, but I can't replicate that case using a simple example at the moment).

Looking at the csv standard (RFC-4180: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), I couldn't find any mentions about the impossibility to have multiline column names, so I assume that it should be possible.

Any help?

Comment: You cannot  have multiline csv.  There would be no way of telling when a row of data ended.  The row with 1;2;3 ends with a invisible return which is the end of the row and col_A ends with a invisible return but continues.

Comment: @jdweng I have to disagree on that. If the parser considered any string encapsed in double quotes as atomic, there shouldn't be any issues on recognizing the actual end of line (see the RFC-4180 standard at paragraph 2.6).
Plus, the parser already does that besides from the header!

Comment: Quoting the spec that you reference: `1.  Each record is located on a separate line, delimited by a line break (CRLF).` and then  `3.  There maybe an optional header line appearing as the first line of the file with the same format as normal record lines.`

Comment: RFCs are written very generic and it is up to the software house to determine which options to implement.  The RFC specifically doesn't say if multi-line is allowed or not allowed.  The ReadCsv method you are using doesn't support option.  Vendor only need to certify that they meet the RFC requirements and asking to have multiline then every vendor would have to implement the option.  Most vendors do not want to spend the money to add code that very few people would use.

Comment: Ok, I opened a new issue on their Github about this problem (https://github.com/fslaborg/Deedle/issues/479).
Do you have any alternative C# libraries that support this feature to suggest? I tried with Python Pandas and it actually works as expected, but I am bound to use C# for this project.

Answer (score 0):

Deedle uses the CSV parser from [F# Data](https://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/) internally to read CSV files.  Testing the latest version of the F# Data CSV parser with your sample input suggests that this now works correctly in F# Data:

```
> let f = CsvFile.Parse(""""
col_A
";"
col_A
2";col_B
1;2;3
4;5;6""", separators=";")
;;
val f : CsvFile

> f.Headers;;
val it : string [] option = Some [|"col_A"; "col_A
2"; "col_B"|]
```

It is probably the case that Deedle is using an older version of the parser. The way to fix this would be to update the Deedle CSV parser to the latest version.